# ¿Could be a unique model of a first order theory including only the definable objects of it??

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why isn't there a unique model of ZFC in which every element is definable?

---

*Spanish version: ¿Por qué en ZFC, aunque por el teorema de incompletitud (y más cosas) tiene infinitos modelos no elementalmente equivalentes, no hay un sólo modelo con todos los objetos definibles en V (el universo del modelo)?*

Comment: I think there's probably an interesting question here, but you need to be make it much clearer. (If language is an issue, write your question in a language you feel more comfortable with, and someone will translate it.) Note that there *are* models of ZFC in which every element is definable, and in fact there are many non-isomorphic such models: see http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597.

Comment: ¿Por qué en ZFC, aunque por el teorema de incompletitud (y más cosas) tiene infinitos modelos no elementalmente equivalentes, no hay un sólo modelo con todos los objetos definibles en V (el universo del modelo)? Please, could it be somebody translate to english correctly? My english is very elemmental

Comment: My Spanish is limited, but I think you are asking why there isn't a unique model of ZFC in which every element is definable. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, this is correct

Comment: Based on your comments, I've rewritten the question and retracted my close vote; please let me know if you disagree with my interpretation of your question.

Comment: No, I think it is all right

Answer (score 1):

There are two questions here:

- Is there a model of ZFC in which every set is definable?

and

- Is there a *unique* such model?

Interestingly enough, the answers are "yes" and "no" respectively:

- There are models of ZFC in which every set - that is, every element of the model - is definable without parameters - these are called *pointwise definable models*. See http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.4597.
- There are in fact *lots* of such models, even though perhaps the existence of any *one* such model is already a shock. This is discussed in the paper linked to above. Note that we even have pointwise definable models which are *not elementarily equivalent* (look at Theorem 4), so there's really a lot of variety going on here!

Comment: I can´t understand if all the objects of the models are definable, they can be non elementarily equivalent. I am trying understand the paper, but my  mathematical level is very low in comparation with a graduate or and advanced undergraduate. My formation is scientific but not pure mathematical

Comment: And in another theories, like NFU, does it happen too???